# Laravel Validation for specific integers

Tags: php, laravel, validation

Let's say I require an input called "points" and there are only an option to select `13` / `26` / `43` points.

If the client tries to send a request with the value of `15` / `23` / any other number that isn't what I gave the option to, the validation will fail.

I was looking at the [Validation Documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/validation), and except using regex, I couldn't find a nicer way to do so.

Comment: accept my answer if it helped you

Comment: @msonowal I'm not currently working on my code, when I do, I'll see if your solution helped me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use built in validation rules for that,
in your controller as here [laravel validation rule in](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/validation#rule-in)

```
$this->validate($request, ['points'=>'in:10,20,30']);
```

so you can pass comma separated values in the parameters